# putting two divs next to each other (labels making some troubles)

Tags: css

I am trying to put 2 divs next to each other but the labels are messing things up..
also I was having trouble to put the INPUT in the same line with the label.

this is my HTML code:

```
<div class="edit_settings">
                <div class="edit_iphone_settings">
                    <div class="title">IPhone Settings</div>
                    <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><label for="label">Last Application Version: </label>
        <input type="text" name="last_app_ver" value="2"><label for="label">Update Status: </label>
        <select name="must_update">
        <option value="0">Ignore</option>
        <option value="1">Force update</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">Suggest for update</option>
        </select><label for="label">Update Message: </label>
        <input type="text" name="message" value="Message"><label for="label">Application URL: </label>
        <input type="text" name="redirect_url" value=""><input type="hidden" name="settings" value="iphone_application">
        <input type="submit" name="edit_iphone_settings" value="Edit"></form>       </div>
                <div class="edit_android_settings">
                    <div class="title">Android Settings</div>
                    <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><label for="label">Last Application Version: </label>
        <input type="text" name="last_app_ver" value="2.07"><label for="label">Update Status: </label>
        <select name="must_update">
        <option value="0">Ignore</option>
        <option value="1">Force update</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">Suggest for update</option>
        </select><label for="label">Update Message: </label>
        <input type="text" name="message" value="Message"><label for="label">Application URL: </label>
        <input type="text" name="redirect_url" value=""><input type="hidden" name="settings" value="android_application">
        <input type="submit" name="edit_android_settings" value="Edit"></form>      </div>
            </div>
```

this is my CSS:

```
.edit_iphone_settings, .edit_android_settings {
    width: 300px;
}
.edit_settings label {
    display: inline-block;
    clear:both;
    width: 200px; 
}
.edit_settings input {
    float: left;
}
.edit_android_settings {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Picture of expected result, or at least a description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

Increase the `width` of the `edit_iphone_settings` container so that the labels and inputs have room to be side by side.

Remove the `clear:both` attribute of the labels

Change `float: left` for the input to `display: inline-block`

```
.edit_iphone_settings, .edit_android_settings {
    width: 500px;
}
.edit_settings label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px; 
}
.edit_settings input {
    display:inline-block;
}
.edit_android_settings {
    clear: both;
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R244w/4/)